# Why isn't the variable added after each input?

Tags: python, loops

The code is designed to add 1 to its variable each time, but in the end result, all variables are still 0.

I'm new and just testing out some basic code, it's supposed to be a voting system.

```
while True:
 A=0
 B=0
 C=0
 vote=input("A, B or C")

 if vote == 'A':
     A + 1
 elif vote == 'B':
     B + 1
 elif vote == 'C':
     C + 1
 elif vote == 'end':
     print ("A got",A,"votes, B got",B,"votes, C got",C,"votes")
 else:
     print ("That's not an option. Try again and Vote A,B or C")
```

When I run the code:

```
A, B or C?A

A, B or C?B

A, B or C?C

A, B or C?A

A, B or C?B

A, B or C?end

A got 0 votes, B got 0 votes, C got 0 votes
```

I expected the output to be:

```
"A got 2 votes,B got 2 votes, C got 1 votes"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: replace `A + 1` with `A += 1` and do the same for `B` and `C`. you aren't changing the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your addition:

```
if vote == "A":
  A = A + 1
elif vote == "B":
  B = B + 1
elif vote == "C":
  C = C + 1
```

You could also use a compound assignment operator:

```
if vote == "A":
  A += 1
elif vote == "B":
  B += 1
elif vote == "C":
  c += 1
```

And you need to declare them outside of the loop, otherwise you're reassigning them every time.

Full code:

```
A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
while True:
 vote = input("A, B or C? ")

 if vote == "A":
     A += 1
 elif vote == "B":
     B += 1
 elif vote == "C":
     C += 1
 elif vote == "end":
     print ("A got", A, "votes, B got", B, "votes, C got", C, "votes")
     break
 else:
     print ("That's not an option. Try again and Vote A,B or C")
```

Output:

```
A, B or C? A
A, B or C? B
A, B or C? C
A, B or C? A
A, B or C? B
A, B or C? end
A got  2  votes, B got  2  votes, C got  1  votes
```

Answer (score 3):

The result of `A + 1` isn't being assigned to anything, you should do `A = A + 1`, or the same in shorter notation: `A += 1`.

```
A=0
B=0
C=0
while True:

 vote=input("A, B or C")

 if vote == 'A':
     A += 1
 elif vote == 'B':
     B += 1
 elif vote == 'C':
     C += 1
 elif vote == 'end':
     print ("A got",A,"votes, B got",B,"votes, C got",C,"votes")
 else:
     print ("That's not an option. Try again and Vote A,B or C")
```

Comment: You're still resetting A, B and C in the loop.